# "Cannot read property of undefined."

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have some simple code that I've written in Python.  It's working.  Now I'm trying to port it to JavaScript.  The code is [here](https://github.com/paul-reiners/chaos-games/blob/main/p5-version/sketch.js).  I'm getting this error:

```
sketch.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'compression_ratio')
    at w (sketch.js:7:39)
    at ifsp (sketch.js:37:13)
    at draw (sketch.js:54:14)
    at p5._main.default.redraw (p5.js:71990:27)
    at _draw (p5.js:64140:25)
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here (Starting line 28).

```js
if (prob_sum > r) {
  attractor_index = j - 1;
} else {
  attractor_index = j;
}
```

If `r` is smaller than `1/3` (probability value that you have defined in line 51) you will decrement `attractors_index` using `j - 1` and if that happens in the first iteration `attractors_index` will be `-1` as `j = 0`. In that case `attractors[attractors_index]` will return `undefined` and you call `w()` with `undefined` instead of the object you expect, hence `attractors.compression_ratio` will not have a property `compression_ratio` and the error is thrown.

You can check/ reproduce that easily by manually setting `r` to `>` or `<` `1/3`.